# 'zsh: command not found' for installed npm packages

Tags: npm, zsh

I've locally installed a npm package without error, and running `npm list --depth=0` confirms it's installed. However running any command from that pkg in terminal returns `zsh: command not found: <command name>`

Based on this SO thread, I've already added `source /Users/YOURSERNAME/.bash_profile` at the beginning of ~/.zshrc but to no avail. Sometimes it also shows `no such file or directory:/Users/YOURSERNAME/.bash_profile` Any other check I could do?

Comment: I don't see what's the point in sourcing .bash_profile, if you run zsh and not bash. It may work by chance, but in general it won't. If a command is not found, you need to fix the PATH, or specify the full path when invoking the command. Look at the _zsh_ man page, section `INVOCATION`, which lists which files zsh in processing automatically under what circumstances, and choose a suitable one for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `.zshrc` file instead:

```
NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.npm-packages"
export PATH="$PATH:$NPM_PACKAGES/bin"
# Preserve MANPATH if you already defined it somewhere in your config.
# Otherwise, fall back to `manpath` so we can inherit from `/etc/manpath`.
export MANPATH="${MANPATH-$(manpath)}:$NPM_PACKAGES/share/man"
```

From https://dev.to/rrampage/5-npm-and-node-tips-to-make-your-machine-safer-3g0l

Reload your zsh settings afterwards:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```